# How do I assign a StackPanel to a specific Grid row/column in code (not XAML)?

Tags: silverlight

Given this XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
```

How can I assign the Grid.Row and Grid.Column attributes in (C#/VB) code?

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
stackPanel.???
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
    MyStackPanel.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
    MyStackPanel.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do the following, where 'myGrid' is the name of your Grid control.

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();

Grid.SetColumn(stackPanel, 0);
Grid.SetRow(stackPanel, 1);

myGrid.Children.Add(stackPanel);
```

Comment: This works also, but Anthony gave me the first answer so he gets the accept. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: From my experience Rich's answer is more typical WPF/Silverlight code as it reads more like the XAML (and I've always thought is easier to discover).

Comment: I actually looked it up and the static methods on the Grid class actually call into the given UIElement's SetValue method.  Obvsiouly both work, just comes down to personal preference.